# Can't change key in Visual Studio 2008 installer

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have a trial version of Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition but also a genuine serial key from Technet. When I install the application, I cannot change the predefined key. How can I then use the unlimited version (what my key represents)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  You will probably have to uninstall the trial version and install from your Technet media.